# Do I need to use Hibernate annotations when using Flyway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, flyway

In my Spring Boot apps, I am using Hibernate and there are several annotations for index, constraint, unique_key, etc. On the other hand, I am also using Flyway for migration in order to create tables besides populating data in the database. In the flyway table creation scripts, I am also using index, constraint creations, etc.

At this stage, I am very confused and feel that I am making one of these operations as redundant. So, what is the most proper way when using Hibernate and Flyway? Because I have also seen some projects where people uses both of them and creating all these elements (index, etc.) on Hibernate Entity definitions and Flyway migration scripts.

Could you clarify me for this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's right the Hibernate and Flyway are mutually independent and have duplicated constraint definitions which is certainly redundant.

In case the using Flyway the Hibernate annotations should omit DDL-related declarations.

Moreover the database modification via hibrnate must be supressed with following Spring configuration property

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: Yeah, I use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` and sometimes when I prefer to use Hibernate table creation, I set it update. At this stage, if I should use one of them, then what is your suggestion about the following issues?

Comment: **1.** Assume that I use Flyway and set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`. Then in case I may need to use Hibernate in the future, I think it is good idea to also implement Hibernate entities by all the necessary index, constraint, etc definitions that are exactly I use in my Flyway scripts. What do you think?

Comment: **2.** I also think that first I make entity implementations properly and then run the app and see the SQL clauses on console. Then I use this sql table, index, constraint creation clauses in my Flyway scripts. Is it a good idea?

Comment: **3.** If a developer uses Hibernate and make all the necessary implementations on Entities, then is there any need to use Flyway except from adding data to database? In this situation, I had troubles as I cannot execute both Hibernate table creation and Flyway. I also used `data.sql`, instead of Flyway, but the problem with that when I run the app second time, it tries to insert the same records. But with flyway, there is not such kind of problems and as the tables are changed, it helps developer to update database. Right?